# Changing other bluetooth device's name in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

Here's my list of bluetooth paired devices:

[image]

It's really not useful when I want to connect to any of those. Is there a way to edit the names to recognize each different device?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the info at:

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2650/how-can-i-change-the-names-of-paired-connected-remote-bluetooth-devices

You need to do this with an editor, but it's not hard.

As root:

```
% cd /var/lib/bluetooth
```

In that directory you will see one or more directories based on MAC Addresses.  If there is more than one you want to use the directory for your computers bluetooth device which you can find by:

```
% hcitool dev
```

Assuming that is:  00:11:22:33:44:55, then you enter that directory:

```
% cd 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

You will see a number of directories for each saved bluetooth device, again by MAC address.  You can go into your bluetooth settings and look at one of your bluetooth devices by double-clicking on it and looking at the Address: field.  If you want to rename a device, edit the file at /info and change the 'Name=' field.

After renaming your devices, restart bluetooth:

```
% service bluetooth restart
```

And then turn bluetooth on and go to your settings and see if the names are updated.  Enjoy!